# onclick change the images sources using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

When I click an image, it changes to an alternate version (`data-other-src`).

When I click an image, also I want to reset all the other image to their `src`. How can I do this?

Here's my code so far:

```
<script>
$(".imageOnOff").live('click', function () {
$(this).attr({src: $(this).attr('data-other-src'),'data-other-src': $(this).attr('src') 
})
   });
 </script>

 <img class="imageOnOff" data-other-src="images/color/1.png" src="images/color/1-1.png"      width="16" height="16">
 <img class="imageOnOff" data-other-src="images/color/2-2.png" src="images/color/2.png"   width="16" height="16">
 <img class="imageOnOff" data-other-src="images/color/3-3.png" src="images/color/3.png" width="16" height="16">
 <img class="imageOnOff" data-other-src="images/color/4-4.png" src="images/color/4.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing data-other-src to src, you should store the original src :

```
$(".imageOnOff").live('click', function () {
  $(".imageOnOff[original-src]").each(function(){
       this.src = $(this).attr('original-src');
       $(this).removeAttr('original-src');
  });
  $(this).attr('original-src', this.src);
  this.src = $(this).data('other-src');
})​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/69bYw/)

Comment: Sorry. There was an error I fixed. See [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/UfCL3/1/).

Comment: As of 1.6 it is adviced to use `$(this).data('otherSrc')` instead of `$(this).data('other-src')` see http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: You could also use `$(".imageOnOff[original-src]").each` to remove the if clause inside.

Comment: Thanks, i have now other problem with that when i try to take id to the input vaule. http://jsfiddle.net/UfCL3/4/

Comment: I don't understand your new question.

Comment: I want to be able to click on the image and change it to other src and take the id of the image and copy it to input has value.
jsfiddle.net/UfCL3/4

Comment: What id ? Your images have no id.

Comment: when i click on it like this onclick="add_image_fb('789');
take the '789' to text input

Comment: Add `inputs.val(id);` and call your function. But this is a totally different and not related question from your original one.

Comment: Thanks and sorry i add new question